# Failed to read key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to read registry keys from folder "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319"
Folder contains two keys SKUs and AssemblyFoldersEx. First key is successfully readed, but second is failed (return null).

How to fix this?

C# code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs", false); // success
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rkey2 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx", false); // failed (returns null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your project in VS and go to `Properties > Build` then change `Platform target` to `Any CPU` then recompile. I suspect your Platform target is x86 and you are running on a 64 bit version of Windows.

Wow6432Node branch of the registry will get you every time :)

Comment: 2. Sorry, I don't understand how does "Wow6432Node" can help me? Could you explain, please?

Comment: I replaced "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx" with "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx" - it works. Thanks!